# Align gridline with axis y in Bar Chart D3 v5

Tags: d3.js, charts, graph-visualization

I have a problem with a bar chart. I insert the gridline, but the effect I get is not as desired as can be seen from the image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gELOp.png)

The gridline is not align with y axis.

The code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart");
var margin = {top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 40, right: 0};
var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .padding(0.1)
    //.paddingOuter(0.2);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

var xAxis = function(g) {
        g
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));
        return g;
    };

var yAxis = function(g) {
        g
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + (margin.bottom - margin.top) + ")")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
        return g;
    };


function gridlines() {
    return d3.axisLeft(y).ticks();
}

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.bottom - margin.top) + ")")
    .call(gridlines()
        .tickSize(-width)
        .tickFormat("")
    );

svg.append("g").attr("class", "x-axis");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis");
```

Thank.

Comment: [This is a pretty good example](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/11110940). Requires 2 sets of grid ticks, one for the axis and one as grid lines

Comment: @pmkro this example is for version 3, I used version 5

Comment: you use margins wrong all else has problems, read an example from the d3-axis doc and use `tickSize(-width)`

Comment: @DrBomber the idea is the same though